# Arrow properties in matplotlib annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

I have Matplotlib version 1.5.1 and I am facing an interesting problem. I want to add an arrow to my plot, which would have heads on each end and specified colour and width. However, studying the [Matplotlib documentation on this matter](http://matplotlib.org/1.5.1/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Annotation), I realized I probably can't have both. I can either have an arrow facing both ends, but this arrow will have default colour and linewidth - this is the option if I include `arrowstyle` in my `arrowprops`, or I can omit `arrowstyle` and set the colour and width in the arrow properties, but then I only have the default arrow. **Is there a way to get both?**

I have this code:

```
plt.annotate('', xy=(p[0][0]-p[0][2], 0), xycoords='data', xytext=(p[0][0], 0), textcoords='data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle: '<|-|>',color='k',lw=2.5))
```

which results in `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

*(Note: `p` is simply a list of lists from which I get my x and y values, I am plotting in a loop)*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to use **arrowprops** to set the color, width and other properties.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.annotate('test', xy=(0.9, 0.9),
             xycoords='data',
             xytext=(0, 0),
             textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle= '<|-|>',
                             color='blue',
                             lw=3.5,
                             ls='--')
           )

ax.set_xlim(-0.1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-0.1,1)
plt.show()
```

Gives this figure:[image]

Comment: which version of matplotlib are you using? As I say, if I have `arrowstyle` in my `arrowprops`, then any `color`, `lw` and other `line2D` properties result in `invalid syntax`

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.0. Note that there is a syntax error in the code you posted - you have "arrowstyle:..." when you should have "arrowstyle=..."

Comment: The problem was carried from my previous version of the code, which had `arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'<|-|>'}` - so it turns out it was merely an error of a different syntax of a dictionary.