# How to put a text label next to a matplotlib.pyplot.arrow?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can manually add a label next to an arrow in Matplotlib 3.4.3. by estimating its location.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
W, H = 2, 3
offsetX = 0.1*W

arrow_style = {"head_width":0.1, "head_length":0.2, "color":"k"}
plt.arrow(x=0, y=0, dx=W, dy=H, **arrow_style)
plt.text(x=W/2+offsetX, y=H/2, s="U")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

I wonder if there is a builtin way to add the label to an arrow and align its label accordingly? if no what is the easiest approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow properties in matplotlib annotate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44489900/7758804). Otherwise, just the the way you have done it.

Comment: Either your current way, or the way in the link. That's how you do it. There's not another way to align the text with the line. [`.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) should have a `rotation` parameter though.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney: I can't find the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit easier to read using [`axes.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html) but somewhat equivalent to the code you've written:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

W, H = 2, 3
arrow_style = {
    "head_width": 0.1,
    "head_length": 0.2,
    "color":"k"
}

plt.arrow(x=0, y=0, dx=W, dy=H, **arrow_style)
plt.annotate('U',
             xy=(W/2, H/2),
             xytext=(10, -10),
             textcoords='offset points')
plt.show()
```

where:

- `xy` is the point (x, y) to annotate
- `xytext` is the position (x, y) to place the text at (default: xy). The coordinate system is determined by textcoords.
- `textcoords` is the coordinate system that xy is given in ('offset points' means the offset in points from the xy value)

So in short, 10 points to the right and 10 points down from the center of the arrow.

Comment: I've updated the answer.